# Infinite chessboard question

Tags: infinity

Suppose there is a species of aliens called cyborgs. There is an infinite chessboard in their homeland. There is 1 cyborg on every square. If cyborgs can jump infinitely far, or jump and land on their same square, is it possible to get 2 cyborgs on the center of every square after 1 jump (a jump is when every cyborg on the chessboard jumps).

another question: What if the cyborg can only jump a finite amount of squares, say 10, or 100 squares?

Comment: Hint: There is a one-to-one correspondence between an infinite set and two disjoint copies of that set.

Comment: The first question is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753354/prove-that-there-are-two-frogs-in-one-square

Comment: @BarryCipra, looking at the index numbers, the duplication would be the other way round wouldn't it?  Not sure whether or not it matters.

Answer (score 2):

Label the rows on half of the board $0,1,2,\ldots$.  Let the cyborg in row $i$, column $j$ jump to row $\lfloor i/2\rfloor$, column $j$.  Do something similar for the other half of the board.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? :). Do you mean just draw a line randomly and say thats half the board, then label 0,1,2 on each half?

Comment: That would do it.

Comment: This is nice because the floor makes 2 on every square.

Answer (score 2):

If each glob can jump at most distance $r$, only those that start out within distance $R+r$ of the origin can end up within distance $R$ of the origin.  But
 as $R \to \infty$, the number of globs that start out within distance $R+r$ of the origin is $\pi (R + r)^2 + O(R) = \pi R^2 + O(R)$.  If after the jump there were two per square, the number within distance $R$ of the origin would have to be $2 \pi R^2 + O(R)$.  So unless the globs reproduce, this is impossible.

Comment: Where would you get the pi from? Sorry if this is obvious.

Comment: @user: He's assuming the length of a jump is measured by Euclidean distance (you didn't specify), thus the set of squares less than a given distance from a given square resembles a disc.